# Finding Obituary from British Newspaper Archive?

Tags: scotland, newspaper, obituary

I was searching family search for info on John Barclay Ormond and Elizabeth Cook and came across a notice from 1944, which is supposedly an obituary for Elizabeth sourced from the British Newspaper Archive.

https://www.familysearch.org/search/record/results?count=20&query=%2Bgivenname%3A%22John%20Barclay%22~%20%2Bsurname%3AOrmond~%20%2Bbirth_place%3AForfar~%20%2Bbirth_year%3A1868-1875~%20%2Brecord_country%3AScotland

Unless one is a latter day saint, they can't view it on Family Search and hence I tried looking on British Newspaper Archive website with no luck.

Can anyone help me find the obituary?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The BNA has the [death notice](https://www.britishnewspaperarchive.co.uk/viewer/bl/0000564/19440613/095/0004) in the Dundee Courier on Tuesday 13 June 1944. It's rather brief:

> ORMOND. At Dundee, on June 11, 1944, John Barclay Ormond, of 115 West High St., Forfar, husband of Elizabeth Cook. Funeral private.

The record was slightly harder to find due to poor automated character recognition in the article - a common enough problem on the BNA. But once I searched for *John "Barclay Ormond"* with filters for 1944 and Scotland, there were three results for June that year. The above was one of them.

There do appear to be numerous other hits on the BNA for John Barclay Ormond, relating to his business and also to a theft charge in 1924.

(If you have a Findmypast account, you can search their "Newspapers & Periodicals" archive which includes the BNA. That way you don't have to pay for images from the BNA. The same article is [here](https://search.findmypast.co.uk/bna/viewarticle?id=bl%2f0000564%2f19440613%2f095) on FMP.)

Comment: It's also possible to identify the newspaper from the FamilySearch citation. This stupidly fails to mention the paper's title but states that it's Digital Folder 102001083. If you go to the FS Catalogue and enter that into the Film Number (yes, you do have to know that the DF is a film equivalent) then you get a load of entries one of which is that "film" and reveals that it's the Dundee Courier & Advertiser. This might or might not reduce the stuff to look through.

Comment: @AdrianB38 Wow, that's a bit of a runaround! Helpful though, I'll keep it in mind for future records, thanks. The iffy OCR quality makes text searching on the BNA equally iffy, but knowing the date or the newspaper lets you find things more easily with broader search terms.

Comment: Yes. Knowing the film number can be remarkably useful when someone's forgotten to specify the exact source - or when even the original just has that annoying title "the Parish Church of XXX" and you're reduced to asking, "Which church? There were 4 in XXX!"